# Cloud function trigger for multiple collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userID}')
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {
        // do something
    });
```

I want this function to trigger for another collection as well, say `offices`. What's the optimal way to do this without copy and pasting the entire thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything in the path can be a wildcard, so if you want to trigger on all collections:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
    .document('{collectionName}/{userID}')
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {
        // do something
    });
```

There is no way to set a single path that triggers on two-but-not-all collections though. If you want that, just minimize the code duplication by isolating that code in a a (regular non-Cloud) function:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userID}')
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {
        doSomething(...)
    });
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
    .document('offices/{officeID}')
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {
        doSomething(...)
    });
function doSomething(...) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answer, you could do the wildcard function with checks:

```js
exports.myfunction = functions.firestore
    .document('{colId}/{docId}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {

        const col = context.params.colId;
        const doc = context.params.docId;

        if (col === 'users' || col === 'offices') {

          return...

        }
        return null;
    });
```